# angular how to not render element content?

Tags: angularjs, dom

there is an ng-show directive in angular, but is there a ng-render directive? that adds  the template of a directive to the dom only when conditions are met?

the problem with ng-show is that it only uses css to hide elements, and since I am creating an enormous list, and I am only displaying the visble elements, I dont want the content of not visible content to be partially rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ng-if](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) or [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch). Neither include content unless your conditions are met.

Comment: i had 1.0.8 ng-if doesnt exist in it, I just updated my angular Js and it works. thanks